# jquery selector referencing the parent class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="1"><input class="a"></input><span class="b"></span></div>
    <div id="2"><input class="a"></input><span class="b"></span></div>
<div id="3"><input class="a"></input><span class="b"></span></div>
```

and I want to write a change() event which will apply to every input box. When the event is fired I want the innerhtml of the corresponding span tag to be updated with an *. How do I write a selector which will allow me to do this? I don't think I can use the $(this) selector because how do I reach the span? Its not like its contained inside of the input. Is there a way to reference the parent (ie: div) and then move down to the span?

Comment: Be sure to upvote good answers, and accept the best answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input.a').change(function() {
    $(this).next('span.b').text('*');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But shouldn't I use a val() since I'm using an input tag?

Comment: @user1015214 But you're not changing the value of the input tag; you're changing the contents of a span.

Answer (score 1):

$(this).siblings("span").html("*");

In fact, you may want to spend a while reading through [jQuery Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").change(function(){
    $(this).next().text("*");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But don't I need to use val if its an input tag?

Comment: It's not an input tag, you are setting the text within a span.